# Trying to display data that has more than a day gap between two dates on the same user?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a query in Toad for Oracle that allows me to pull users who have had more than a one day gap between their previous and current supervisor(s) with a Supervisor Type of 'Registered Principal'.

For example, if the user has a Supervisor with an end date of 10/20/2019, I would expect to see a Supervisor assigned by 10/21/2019. If not then I would want those exceptions displayed since as of 10/22/2019, there is a one day gap. If date of '12/31/9999' is displayed then that means the supervisor is current.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.AssocID, a.SupervisorAssocID, TRUNC(a.StartDate), 
   TRUNC(a.EndDate), a.SupervisorType
FROM TableName a
INNER JOIN (SELECT AssocID, StartDate, EndDate
            FROM TableName
           ) b ON a.AssocID = b.AssocID
WHERE a.StartDate != TRUNC(b.StartDate) 
   AND TRUNC(b.EndDate) >  a.StartDate
   AND a.StartDate != TRUNC(b.EndDate)
   AND a.SupervisorType = 'Registered Principal';
```

I expect to only see users who have had a gap of more than one day between Supervisors.

[image: Picture of Sample Data]

Comment: Please edit your question to show sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEAD` analytic function to get the next start date:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         LEAD( startdate ) OVER (
           PARTITION BY AssocId
           ORDER BY StartDate ASC
         ) AS next_startdate
  FROM   tablename a
  -- WHERE SupervisorType = 'Registered Principal'
)
WHERE SupervisorType = 'Registered Principal'
AND   TRUNC( enddate ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY < TRUNC( next_startdate )
```

*Note: its unclear where you want to filter on `SupervisorType`; your query makes it seem like it should be the outer query but it could be the inner query if you only want to consider differences between Registered Principals and not any other type of supervisor.*

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm getting an error message "ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0". The date fields are timestamps if that helps. Please let me know your thoughts, thank you!